# Action on click of notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I have a view which I want to make visible and invisible on click of a notification. I have successfully created the notification but cannot create click event on it. Here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_plus);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, BroadcastTV.class);
        resultIntent.setAction("set_tv");
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);


        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
```

**BroadcastTV:**

```
public class BroadcastTV extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action_name = intent.getAction();
        Toast.makeText(context, "working fine ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (action_name.equals("set_tv")) {
            if (MainActivity.isVisible)
            {
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, FlyBitch.class));
                MainActivity.isVisible = false;
            }
            else if (!MainActivity.isVisible)
            {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, FlyBitch.class));
                MainActivity.isVisible = true;
            }

        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: have redirected to the activity when you click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest file as shown in example below

```
<receiver android:name="com.app.packagename.BroadcastTV"></receiver>
```

Comment: My bad, should have considered this thing. Thanks for waking me up ;)